# Translation of statement in French

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-french

Since non-mathematicians might miss some subtleties, I ask for a translation of the following statement:

> Soit $Y$ un processus positif, optionnel, et de la classe $(D)$, s.c.i à droite.
>
> Nous définissons par récurrence $I^{n}=R(I^{n-1})$ et $I^{0}=Y$.
>
> La suite $I^{n}$ est un suite croissante de processus optionels, s.c.i. Sa limite, notée I, est l'enveloppe de Snell du processus $Y$ par rapport à la chronologie $\tau$ de l'ensemble des t.a etages rationnelles.
>
> Le caractère s.c.i de $Y$ permet d'identifier le processus $I$ a l'envelope de Snell optionnelle de $Y$. $J$, qui est alors un processus continu  à droite.

Merci!

Comment: Have you tried just throwing it in to google translate? It does a reasonable job apart from with the acronym (obviously), "suite" and "etages rationnelles" - but gets you something that is probably pretty close to parsable

Comment: @Nadiels it is even worse then with common sentences. And the acronym is important.

Comment: Huh, see I think its pretty amazing with common sentences. But even with a naive copy paste job (which handles the maths badly) it seems alright, for example -- "The $I_n$ suite is a growing suite of optional processes, s.c.i. Its limit, noted $I$, is the envelope of Snell of the process $Y$ with respect to the chronology $\tau$ of all rational stages" obviously this is a bit sketch, but swap suite for a different definition and its getting pretty close. Anyways hopefully you will get a more helpful response

Comment: "ensemble des t.a etages rationnelles" What is the shorthand **t.a** standing for here?

Comment: @Did tout alors? :)

Comment: @JEJ Most probably not. To be honest, I am silghtly surprised that you instantly accepted the translation proposed below, because of this problem which it passes over, and also because of several rather awkward formulations in the French text ("la classe (D), s.c.i à droite", "chronologie"), which should be elucidated before we could decide that we have a proper translation in English. FYI, at the moment, the most plausible option is that "t.a" stands for **temps d'arrêt** (stopping times).

Comment: @Did it was sufficent for me to feel comfartable with certain points of the statement. But thanks for that last point. Your are probably right I saw the notation $t.a \in \tau$ for some chronlogie $\tau$ which is a family of stop times.

Comment: "it was suffic[i]ent for me to feel comf[o]rtable with certain points of the statement" Even not knowing what the crucial notation $\tau$ is referring to? This is surprising, to say the least.

Comment: @Did I do know.

Comment: What is the source of the text in French?

Comment: Les aspects probabilistes du contrôle stochastique by el Karoui , chronoligie is defined on page 121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be an optional positive process, of class $(D)$, semi-continuous to the right.

Define the recurrence relation $I^{n}=R(I^{n-1})$ and $I^{0}=Y$.

The sequence $I^{n}$ is an increasing sequence of optional process, semi-continuous. It has a limit I, which is the Snell enveloppe of process $Y$ with respect to chronology $\tau$, the set of rational stages.

The semi-continuity of $Y$ allows us to identify process $I$ to the optional Snell envoloppe of $Y$. $J$ which is a continuous process to the right.

J'espère que ça te convient!